# list names as vector in list

Tags: r, list

What is the quickest way to get from the following list:

```
 set.seed(1)
 mylist <- list(1:2,1:3,1:4)
 names(mylist) <- sample(LETTERS,3)

 mylist
$J
[1] 1 2

$V
[1] 1 2 3

$Z
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

to a list with an extra vector containing the names of list i.e.

```
mylist
$J
[1] 1 2
[2] J J

$V
[1] 1 2 3
[2] V V V
$Z
[1] 1 2 3 4
[2] Z Z Z Z
```

the result could equally be a list of data frames.  Some sort of

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) { data.frame(x=x,y=names(x)})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another option:

```
df<-stack(mylist)
split(df, df$ind)
```

Maybe `stack(mylist)` is all you really need?

Comment: +1 nice stack function !just maybe change df variable name to not confuse!

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I like @Matthew Plourde's use of `stack`

Here's an option using `mapply` that preserves the same structure of the original list

```
mapply(function(L, N) 
     {names(L) <- rep(N, length(L)); L},   mylist, names(mylist))
```

#### Results:

```
$G
G G 
1 2 

$J
J J J 
1 2 3 

$N
N N N N 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: you could also use `lapply` and a similar indexing strategy:  `lapply(seq_along(mylist), function(x) data.frame(x=names(mylist[x]), y=mylist[x]))`

Comment: @Justin, although your `lapply` method lines up the names with the values, I dont think such a data frame is what the OP was looking for

Comment: Operating under the assumption that the last line of code the OP wrote was intentional, I think otherwise...